# How to deploy an ASP.NET Core targetting net452 project as an IIS application of a Web Site in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I want to  deploy an ASP.NET Core RTM  web app targeting net452  to an IIS application and not IIS website. I am using IIS 10 (windows 10)

I previously had an `ASP.net 5 RC1` project and deployed it to an IIS application folder in IIS using the method described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/416) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1374)

I need to run the website as a application under my website e.g. http://locahost/mysite in IIS and I achieved this  in RC1 by adding the following code line to the `Configure` method in my `Startup.cs`

```
app.Map("/MyApplication", (app1) => this.Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory));
```

After I converted my project to ASP.net core  it can run successfully in Visual Studio however the above code now just gives me a blank page in IIS when I access the URL `http://localhost/mysite`

I have made sure I have everything I needed in my code from the [ASP.NET documentation website](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) on how to deploy ASP.NET Core to IIS including installing the  installer and doing an `iireset`.

[image]
 But after following everything required to setup I get the same blank screen.

Now I am stuck.

I then enabled logging. When I enabled logging in my `web.config` I get the following when I try to access my website

```
info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
      User profile not available. Using 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\AutoGenKeys\S<removed>\DataProtection' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\mydeployfolder
Now listening on: http://localhost:8305/mysite
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/mysite
```

From the above you can see it picked up I put in my browser the url, and created a log entry however the end result in the browser is still a blank page.

I then read the log from the start and for one or other reason it is listening on port 8308 and not port 80. So I put in `http://localhost:8305/mysite` in my browser and I get the following in the log

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:8305/mars  
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware[0]
      'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token '<removed>', request rejected.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.9426ms 400 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:8305/favicon.ico  
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware[0]
      'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token '52561883-06a6-46ce-b8dc-5daadb6e83c0', request rejected.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.7004ms 400
```

and still a blank page.

I just want to host the web app which targets  on IIS and previously did it in ASP.NET 5 RC. What am I doing wrong in ASP.NET Core or is it not possible anymore?

Comment: whats is your `applicationUrl` in `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: that is the dev url when I debug from visual studio http://localhost:49753/ launchUrl is http://localhost:5000

Comment: Did you check that your code work as site ?

Comment: code work in debug and in release mode running from Visual Studio. Just does nothing when publishing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the

```
app.Map("/MyApplication", (app1) => this.Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory));
```

workaround is no longer required in ASP.NET Core RC2 or RTM where as it  was required in RC1